# Adding selected feature to new layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to isolate one or more features in a layer, and add them to a different one. I've set up an empty layer (tempLayer) with the same fields as the one I'm selecting features from (layer1).

I then use:

```
query = '"AreaIDlvl0" = 25007'
selection = layer1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer1.selectByIds([k.id() for k in selection])
for feature in layer1.getSelectedFeatures():
    tempLayer.addFeatures([feature])
```

But it returns False.
I've also tried adding all features:

```
for feature in layer1.getFeatures():
    tempLayer.addFeatures([feature])
```

it returns False for all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your `tempLayer` editable before being able to insert features.

`layer.startEditing()` or `with edit(layer)`.

There is also no need to go through the selection, you already have the features from the first request.

```
query = '"AreaIDlvl0" = 25007'
features = layer1.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
with edit(tempLayer):
    for feature in features:
        tempLayer.addFeature(feature)
```